# WPF Visibilty binding works only in Constructor, Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I am using caliburn micro, and wanted to toggle visibility of 2 controls. Below is my xaml implementaion, In constructor if I set the property values to true/false , the controls are displayed/hidden accordingly. But I change those properties in an event to true/false which is not reflecting in the visibility of the controls. Below is how the properties are implemented. How the binding works in Constructor but not when i set it during an event.

```
private bool _bDisplayProjOutput;

    private bool _bDisplayBrowseOutput;

    public bool DisplayBrowseBtn
    {
        get { return _bDisplayBrowseOutput; }
        set 
        { 
            _bDisplayBrowseOutput = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayBrowseBtn);
        }
    }


    public bool DisplayFilesList
    {
        get { return _bDisplayProjOutput; }
        set 
        { 
            _bDisplayProjOutput = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DisplayFilesList);
        }
    }



<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           ..
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Path=DisplayBrowseBtn, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
            <TextBlock Text="Test Display" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DocItemsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="False"  CanUserAddRows="False"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Visibility="{Binding Path=DisplayFilesList, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            ..
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the ViewModel for another control, So, replaced `NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ...);` with `OnPropertyChanged()`. Then it started working.